# Fix React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am designing a component using the useEffect Hook and I seem to be encountering an error in the code where I have a axios call. I get the error of:

**Error:**

`React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'formData'. Either include it or remove the dependency array. You can also do a functional update 'setFormData(f => ...)' if you only need 'formData' in the 'setFormData'`

I am not sure why I get this error because I mention in the code where its originating from and since I also use the information outside the hook it seems to be logically correct. The end result I am looking for was to have the formData state updated to the values received from the axios request. However, the values stay the same. So again not sure what I did wrong.

**Code:**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Aux from '../../hoc/Aux';
import Navbar from './Navbar';
import WeekSelection from './WeekSelection';
import axios from 'axios';



const Landing = () => {

    //useState to set up information
    const[formData,setFormData] = useState({
        name: 'Test',
        artist: 'Test',
        album: 'Test',
        duration: 'Test',
        url: 'https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67706c0000da848d0ce13d55f634e290f744ba'
    });



    const {
        name,
        artist,
        album,
        duration,
        url

    } = formData;

    


           


        useEffect(() => {
              
            axios.post('/')
            .then(res => {
                setFormData({
                    ...formData,
                    name: res.name,
                    artist: res.artist,
                    album: res.album,
                    duation: res.duration,
                    url: res.url
                });

                console.log(name);
                console.log(artist);
                console.log(album);
                console.log(duration);
                console.log(url);
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.error(err.message);
            });

          

        
        }, []);




    return (
         
        <Aux>
            <div className="myLeft">

                <div className="company-name">
                    <span className="headphones">
                        <i className="fas fa-headphones"></i>
                    </span>
                    <h1 className="titleStyle">SilverStone</h1>
                </div>

                <WeekSelection />
                <WeekSelection />
                <WeekSelection />
                <WeekSelection />
                <WeekSelection />
            </div>

            <div className="myRight">
                <Navbar />
                 
            <div className="test">
                <img src="https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b2730a2d690b414896b2bd008a53" alt="Spotify Cover Art" />
            </div>

            <div className="song-data">
                <h2 className="week">Monday</h2>



                <div className="song-box-data">
                    <div className="rectangle-1"></div>
                    <p className="song-styles">Song</p>
                    <div className="music-icon"></div>
                    
                </div>
                <p className="seeYouAgain">See You Again</p>
                    <div className="artist-line">                
                        <div className="by">By:</div>
                        <div className="artist-line-name">Wiz Knalifa ft. Charlie Puth</div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="time-info">                
                        <div className="duration">Duration</div>
                        <div className="minutes">4:54 min</div>
                        <div className="clock">
                            <i className="far fa-clock"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
            </div>

        </Aux>

     
    )
};


export default Landing;
```

Comment: add formData to your dependency array

`useEffect(() => {
   ...
}, [ formData ]);`

Comment: You're overwriting every property of `formData` so there's no use in spreading it, you can just remove `...formData`.

Comment: @RameshReddy I'm pretty sure he meant that as a placeholder for the existing code and not as a spread operator :)

Comment: @SakoBu My comment is for the OP.

Comment: You may want to read this post: https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/

Comment: @AbhaY When I make the adjustment like you said it runs in a continuous loop, it continuously calls it on the client-side.

Comment: yes, because every time formData changes, effect runs, that's why infinite loop.

Comment: @RameshReddy Yes, I did remove it but still constantly refetching 'undefined' data in a loop.

Comment: the thing you are trying is an anti-pattern.

Comment: @kane_004 remove `...formData` and continue using `[]` as you only want the `useEffect` to run when the component is mounted.

Answer (score 0):

Since `useEffect` is simply a function, it can't know by itself what variables are in your component or when they are updated. As the error message states already, you must include `formData` in the dependecy array of `useEffect` (the second parameter of the function), so that the function you provide to `useEffect` runs each time its dependencies (`formData` in this case) update.

The error message also mentions that you can simply remove the dependency array, which will make your hook run on every update of your component. Passing in an empty array to `useEffect` effectively means "Run this once when the component is created", which contradicts the use of your `formData` in your hook, since that variable will change throughout the lifetime of the component. Here is the relevant part of the React documentation : https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects

If you have any other doubts about React Hooks, I recommend reading the docs carefully. They are pretty complete and should answer most questions you have about hooks and reactivty.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can fix it.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const Landing = () => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .post("/")
      .then(res => {
        const { name, artist, album, duration, url } = res;
        setFormData({ name, artist, album, duration, url });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.error(err.message);
      });
  }, []);

  if (!formData) return <p>loading</p>;
  return <div>{JSON.stringify(formData)}</div>;
};

export default Landing;
```

Comment: Note: I'have removed your component, which you can place back after understanding this code.

Comment: The code did not work, but than thank you regardless